# JQuery AJAX inexplicable parseerror

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

My AJAX scripts are all functioning perfectly and the success function is working yet the script still hits the error message. I have determined that the problem is parseerror. What I have not determined is why this is happening and how to stop it.

AJAX

```
var dataString = 'title=' + title + '&price=' + price + '&duration=' + duration + '&dives=' + dives + '&hire=' + hire + '&date=' + date + '&currency=' + currency + '&cost=' + cost + '&supplier=' + supplier;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
             url: '<?php echo $thisposturl?>?catadd',
             data: dataString,
             beforeSend: function() {
                 $('#loadwheel-new').html('<img id="BKloader" src="http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/structure/icons/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" width="30" height="30"/>');
                 },
                  error: function() {
                 $('#loadwheel-new').html('lkk');
                 },
                 dataType:'json',
              success: function(data) {
     $('#CollapsiblePanel' + data.CATid).load('<?php echo $thisposturl?> #' + data.CATid);
     ;
} });
```

PHP

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$CATid = $the_post_id;
$date = get_the_time('Y-m-d');
$price = $_POST['price'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$dives = $_POST['dives'];
$hire = $_POST['hire'];
$currency = $_POST['currency'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];
$supplier = $_POST['supplier'];


echo json_encode( array('title'=>$title, 'CATid'=>$CATid, 'date'=>$date, 'price'=>$price, 'duration'=>$duration, 'dives'=>$dives, 'hire'=>$hire, 'currency'=>$currency, 'cost'=>$cost, 'supplier'=>$supplier));
```

Comment: does the parse error occur on the server-side or on the client side?

Comment: Sever side. It is something to do with the JSON I think

Comment: What is the result you are receiving back from the server? Could you copy and paste it using firebug. You should be able to look at the response received from the server.

Comment: I had this happen recently in ColdFusion: my problem was that additional information was being returned with the JSON, so even though it was well-formed JSON when it was created, it couldn't be parsed correctly. (I had page-level debugging turned on, so debug info was included.)

Answer (score 1):

Try clean buffer on server side with `ob_clean` before output your JSON

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when calling $.getJSON, but I think it comes down to the same thing, malformed JSON.  I got around it by wrapping my json parsing in a JavaScript try/catch.

Comment: Could you elaborate that a bit JacaScript try/catch?

Comment: Sure - this won't fix your JSON encoding errors, but will at least let you know that something went wrong to alert you to look into it, and also stop your whole page from failing if something goes wrong with the JSON. I do something like this within your Ajax success callback function: 

try {
  var response = $.parseJSON(response);
  //Parse json here
} catch (err) {
  //If bad json, in development I 
  may just console.log(err)
}

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to make code show up in comments, sorry for the lack of formatting...

Comment: .. you can use reverse tick marks to display `code` in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this instead?

```
var dataString = {
    'title': title,
    'price': price,
    'duration': duration,
    'dives': dives,
    'hire': hire,
    'date': date,
    'currency': currency,
    'cost': cost,
    'supplier': supplier
};
```