# jQuery AJAX sends data but fires error

Tags: jquery

I have a weird problem while processing a form from AJAX.

It is working as expected but for some reason it fires an error instead of success.

This is the code:

```
$(".sendBtn").click(function(e) {

    campaigncode = "#####";
    senderemail = "test@email.com";
    subject = "Test";
    sendermessage = "Test";
    targetURL = "www.abc.com";

    email = $(".email").val();

    //Email Validation
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;  
    if( email ==""){//Empty Check
        alert('Please enter your email');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        if(!emailReg.test( email )) {//Email validation
            alert('*Please enter valid email');
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {

    //Ajax Start
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://services.ninemsn.com.au/sendtofriend/sendtofriendService.aspx?showdefaultmessage=true",
            context: document.body,
            type: "POST",
            data: {campaigncode:campaigncode, recipientemail:email, senderemail:senderemail, subject:subject, sendermessage:sendermessage, targetURL:targetURL},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function() {
                alert('Success');
            },
                        error: function() {
                                    alert('Error');
                              }

        });//Ajax End

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Is the AJAX event firing from the same domain or cross domain?

Comment: fires from cross domain but it works cause I can receive email but just alert error

Comment: Guessing his site isn't ninemsn, so it's cross-domain. @PraveenKumar However it's JSONP, which is designed for cross-domain.

Comment: yes your are right Scotty. jsonp works for cross domain

Comment: Change to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` so you can get more information and paste it here.

Comment: It just alert error. But how do you get value of them

Comment: @Dips:
`error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
}`

Comment: try Scotty's suggestion and alert textStatus

Comment: here is the error `Error: parsererror Error: jQuery172010452208149023878_1342752436990 was not called`

Comment: What do you mean by "It is working as expected"? Other than calling your error function what happens? Does NineMSN provide an API reference for the send to friend service?

Comment: It functions what I wanted to do. It sends the data to server but just responds error instead success

Comment: It just seems a bit weird to me that the only data you're supplying to the service is an email address - how does it know what to send to that address? Again, is there an API reference for that service?

Comment: It is send mail service. yes it has API ref.

Comment: OK, I guess I assumed it was obvious I was asking you to supply a link to the API reference. At the time I thought maybe I could have a bit of a look at the reference to see if your code was missing anything. Now I'm more or less out of patience...

Comment: I have updated with all the code that I have

Answer (score 2):

From your error, looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095307/jquery-json-response-always-triggers-a-parseerror) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type) are similar. The "jQuery_172blah was not called" error is referring to a jsonp callback (which wasn't called because parsing somewhere else failed). I'd suggest...

1. Try setting `crossDomain: true`, then also set `dataType:text` or `dataType:text json`.
2. Try passing `data` as a **string** instead of a dict.
3. Try setting `jsonp:false` and `jsonpCallback`. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on these.

For example:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    recipientemail: email
});
$.ajax({
    url: "http://services.ninemsn.com.au/sendtofriend/sendtofriendService.aspx?",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'text json',
    data: jsonString,
    ...
```

Comment: But using `dataType: 'text json',` doesn't send the data

Comment: @Dips: Try passing `data` as a JSON string, see suggestion above.

Comment: No progress. Still same problem

Comment: @Dips: Which version of jQuery are you using? The parsererror sounds like a bug, or some argument not configured correctly...

Comment: @Dips: If you can figure out what's causing the parsererror, that will be it. I've added one more suggestion above. I really think your `data` needs to be a **string** and use `dataType:json`. I'm guessing ajax() is causing a parser error because data is a dict...

Answer (score 0):

JSONP requires that the response be wrapped in some kind of callback function.

Try to log the response to the console to see what was sent back

```
success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
```

Also, try wrap the response into an object using $.parseJSON:

```
success: function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the server, send it with "response . AllowGet"