# Phonegap AJAX call fails

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to get a simple phonegap app to communicate with my server.

This is my javascript:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.drimmit.com/test',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){
                //data loaded
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                //error loading data
                alert('no data');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I've also whitelisted the domain in the config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://www.drimmit.com" subdomains="true"/>
```

On my server, I'm doing a simple echo statement.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo 'hello from server';

?>
```

In the end, I just get a popup (iOS) saying "no data", meaning it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have mentioned the request type as jsonp, but from server you are rendering json, hence the issue, if u remove the "jsonp: 'jsoncallback'" statement from your ajax call , it should work fine, also replace dataType:'jsonp' with dataType:'json'.

PS - jsonp is used if you are making cross doamin requests, but in phonegap it is not required as you have already whitelisted the domain.

Comment: oh, I missed the datatype parameter, change it to json, replace" dataType: 'jsonp'" with "dataType:'json'"

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned the `dataType: 'jsonp'` in response you are sending the string

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode('hello from server');
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this doesn't work at the moment. still responds with no data :(

Comment: error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
            alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
        }
replace error function with this and see what is the error message and add in your question

Comment: I'm getting a "ERREUR: parsererror" followed by "ERREUR: Error: jQuery191023364612134173512_1365495173377 was not called".

Appreciate your help so far!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095307/jquery-json-response-always-triggers-a-parseerror
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359224/parsererror-after-jquery-ajax-request-with-jsonp-content-type
see these answers may it will solve your issue