# Ajax response throws an Syntax Error: Json @ position 4

Tags: php, json, ajax, yii2, response

In my Yii2 application I am tryng to send bootstrap multiselect dropdown values to my controller and according to the arra sent perform actions in the controller. It always hits the error, I have alerted the thrownError. I get the error as 
**Syntax Error: Unexpected token < in Json at position 4**

I cannot understand where am I going wrong.

**my dropdown list code**

```
 <select id="lstFruit" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">
    <optgroup label ="General">
   <?php for ($i = 0; $i<$genCount; $i++){?>

              <option value="<?php echo $genRole[$i] ?>">
                  <?php echo $genRole[$i] ?>
              </option>
          <?php } ?>  
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label ="Chemicals">
   <?php for ($i = 0; $i<$chemCount; $i++){?>

              <option value="<?php echo $chemRole[$i] ?>">
                  <?php echo $chemRole[$i] ?>
              </option>
          <?php } ?>  
   </optgroup>

    <optgroup label ="Risk Assessment">
   <?php for ($i = 0; $i<$riskCount; $i++){?>

              <option value="<?php echo $riskRole[$i] ?>">
                  <?php echo $riskRole[$i] ?>
              </option>
          <?php } ?>  
   </optgroup>

</select>
```

**My ajax request**

```
 jQuery("body").on("click", ".rolesEdit", function() {

        var roles = $("#lstFruit").val();
        alert(roles.length);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data:{roles: roles},
        url: "'.$url.'",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data.status){
               alert(data);
            }else{
               alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
                   if(thrownError == "Forbidden"){window.location = "http://test.qsims.com/index.php/product/check-file"; }
        }
    });
});
```

**my controller**

```
  if(Yii::$app->request->post('roles')){
           $p = Yii::$app->request->post();
           $roles = $p["roles"];
           $count = count($roles);

           \app\modules\auth\models\SimAuthAssignment::deleteAll(['in','user_id', $id]);

            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
                $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;         
                $authorRole = $auth->getRole($roles[$i]);
                $auth->assign($authorRole, $model->user_id);
            }
             echo BaseJson::encode([
                'status'=>true,
                'id'=>$model->user_id,                
            ]);

        }
```

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you print and post JSON string? Error seems to be in JSON string.

Comment: As the error states, the issue is in the JSON. What is the response from your AJAX request?

Comment: I cannot dump post because I am sending an ajax request

Comment: @MohanPrasad you can. If you dump it, it will be returned in the AJAX response. Open you console terminal and look into it.

Comment: I would also do `console.log(roles)` after you get `#lstFruit` value to see how your data is being sent to your controller.

Comment: Array[2]0: "Manager"1: "Staff"length: 2__proto__: Array[0].. that it is sending to the controller

Comment: @Hicaro is anything wrong the way i's sending the data to the controller?

Comment: Yes, you should serialize your data before sending it. Use `$( "#lstFruit" ).serialize();` instead of `$("#lstFruit").val();`

Comment: if I do that in the console log it returns empty array

Comment: var roles = $( "#lstFruit" ).val()+$( "#lstFruit" ).serialize(); this is sending the data as a string..but still I get the same output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131815/discussion-between-hicaro-and-mohan-prasad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is causing because of my url. My url contains a callback ?=

```
$url=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("user/update?id=".$id);
```

This is a magic string which activates JSONP functionality.

I created a new action in the controller and changed the url to the newly created action which resolved the issue for me.

```
  $url=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("user/roles-ajax");
```

Answer refrenced from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095307/jquery-json-response-always-triggers-a-parseerror) - @Abdul