# Problem to retrieve JSON after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made an AJAX function with jQuery. The function works properly, and server return a JSON, but I can't use it in my JS script

Server side :

```
$array = array();

$array["count"] = count($accounts_list)."";

    for($i=0; $i<count($accounts_list); $i++)
    {
        $account = $accounts_list[$i];

        $array["marker"]["name"] = $account->name;
        $array["marker"]["lat"] = $account->map_latitude;
        $array["marker"]["lon"] = $account->map_longitude;
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
```

Client side :

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "index.php?module=cap_Maps&action=AddMarkers", 
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "error"){
            $(".tr_legend").before("<tr><td colspan='2' id='error'><span class='error_maps'>Erreur lors du chargement des marqueurs</span><td><tr>");
        }
        else {
            alert(data);
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data )
                alert (obj.count);
        }

    }  
});
```

JSON returns by server:

```
{"count":"371","marker":{"name":"WAMPFLER","lat":"49.02751610","lon":"2.10611230"}}
```

Function `alert(data)` returns my JSON, but if I try to parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON( data )`, It doesn't work and `alert(obj.count);` doesn't open.

**EDIT**

I have add error function:

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
                },
```

And error occured :

```
XMLHttpRequest={"count":"358"}
textStatus=parsererror
errorThrown=Invalid JSON: {"count":"358"}
```

**EDIT**

If I had `contentType: "application/json",` in my AJAX, I can return a static string which is considered as json, but if I try to execute other php code on my server, AJAX returns an `500 Internal server error`

Comment: The similar question is asked before [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631418/jquery-getjson-ajax-parseerror) Check this out. Hope this helps

Comment: I really don't understand why jQuery throws this error; `{"count":"358"}` is completely valid.

Comment: Can I send an associative array instead of JSON ? If I do this, I will not have problems with JSON ;)

Comment: Have you ever tried jQuery.getJSON() instead of jQuery.parseJSON()? (Converted the answer to a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output buffer didn't empty so AJAX received buffer content + JSON so it wasn't a valid JSON.

I use `ob_clean()` on server side just before output my JSON and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON('{"count":"371","marker":{"name":"WAMPFLER","lat":"49.02751610","lon":"2.10611230"}}');

alert(json.count);
```

maybe you forget to give a string ' ' to parseJSON.

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten quotes around data, but if I try to add this. I have an error in firebug `JSON.parse
[Stopper sur une erreur] (function(a,b){function cw(a){return f...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=f})(window);`

Answer (score 0):

From [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types):

> The `json` type parses the fetched data file as a JavaScript object and returns the constructed object as the result data.

So you don't need `jQuery.parseJSON`, as the returned string already is parsed.

Comment: I just discover `dataType: "json"` make error : I can't execute function `success`. When I try `alert(data.count)`, it 's `undefined`, so I think it isn't parse.

Comment: @Corum: Then add an `error` callback function and see what the error is.

Comment: If I specify `dataType: "json"`, code which is after isn't executed. If I remove this line and spy `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` with Firebug, I have error `Invalid JSON: [{"count":"358"}]`

Comment: @Corum: Yes, that's exactly why I proposed to add an `error` handler and see what the error is.

Comment: @Corum: please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): “A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." ”

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Thanks, I have edited my question to add `error` function and the error

Answer (score 0):

instead of using parseJson can you try just using eval.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "index.php?module=cap_Maps&action=AddMarkers", 
    data: dataString, 
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "error"){
            $(".tr_legend").before("<tr><td colspan='2' id='error'><span class='error_maps'>Erreur lors du chargement des marqueurs</span><td><tr>");
        }
        else {
            alert(data);
                var obj = eval(data);
                alert (obj.count);
        }

    }  
});
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not sending the JSON with proper format from your server try to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.