# AJAX - JQuery GET Callback not working but JSON file access ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

My code looks like this:

```
$.get('http://files.mysite.com/data.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "jsonp");
```

When I take a look inside the `Network` menu from Firebug I can see a valid call to my `JSON` file and when I open it, it conains all the information.

But the `Console` remains silent. No sign of an `AJAX` call nor my logging of `data`.

My `AJAX` call is not on the same domain as my `JSON` file. Thats why I'm using `jsonp`

Any ideas??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, if you get a result but the console stays quiet you could have issues with the JSON itself... try [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to find issues.

Also I would recommend you don't use getJson etc.

```
$.ajax({
    url: http://files.mysite.com/data.json,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("Loading");
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },

    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);
    },

    complete: function () {
        console.log('Finished all tasks');
    }
});
```

This way you get some error handling and other nice little features, you could add a loading spinner via beforeSend, and remove it via complete :)

Edit:
Replace the error function with the one below, that should give us a better idea of what the problem is :)

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(jqXHR);
  console.log(textStatus);
  console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: my console tells me the following: Loading

Error

Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success" }

Finished all tasks - The Network menu still loads the file, the content and interprets the JSON...

Comment: and jsonlint tells me that my JSON is valid

Comment: So it's running the error function fine, just not the success function?

Comment: it seems this way. the ajax-call returns always an error. so i just tried putting the same (then another) json locally and the same error occurs. but both json's are valid... ?!

Comment: Updated my answer with a better error function, let us know what you get in the console :)

Comment: now i get this: success - parsererror - Error: jQuery1800034901611723603954_1346859231798 was not called

Comment: I honestly don't know how to fix the issue you're having now, sorry, I tried.

I can try help by adding links :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631418/jquery-getjson-ajax-parseerror

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use $.getJSON instead of get if you know that the response will be json. The console should work now

```
$.getJSON('http://files.mysite.com/data.json', function(data) {
 console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Case sensitive! It's `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

**jsonp** is not supported see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests), only *xml, json, script, html*
so use **json** instead if you dont have cross domain policy issue

```
$.get('http://files.mysite.com/data.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: @Ron in that case, use $.ajax with type:"get", jsonp is supported in ajax method :) also, this post will help http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/