# Reload a page with JavaScript (within jquery ajax-request)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

my question is, what I have to do to reload a page with javascript. I have written the following function:

```
  function update(id, name)
    {
    if(/^\d+$/.test(id))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "/url/action/param/" + id + "/param2/" +  unescape(name),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#overlay").fadeOut().remove();
                if(data.status == '200') {
                  window.location.reload()
                }
                else if(data.error) {
                    $("#messages").html(data.error).fadeIn();
                }
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the ajax-request is successfull, the result is a json-object:

```
{"status":"200"}
```

But the window doesn't reload. If I use the this line

```
window.location.reload()
```

at firebug and execute it, the browser window reloads.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need to reload? Why would you need to reload. Is there an issue you solve by reloading that may be solved differently?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data type to JSON:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: Also see this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query

Comment: @Bindu cheers, feel free to accept it then by clicking the V icon to the left.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error end of `window.location.reload()` . Add semicolon after this line and try again.

Comment: Semicolons are optional except in inline event handlers

Comment: You said you use firebug maybe you must check your conditions. Did you observed your code falls to that code line?