# REST api authentication through json

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I'm trying to do a simple REST api in a CakePhp app, using a [REST plugin](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin) I found,  which for Authorization uses http headers.

My question is, how can I supply through jQuery using json, a header like for example:

`Authorization: TRUEREST username=wwwww&password=zzzzz&apikey=xxxxxyyyyyyy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  beforeSend: function(x) {
    x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'TRUEREST username=wwwww&password=zzzzz&apikey=xxxxxyyyyyyy');
  },
  // ...
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will try and next time read better the docs :)

Comment: @pedross The docs aren't all that helpful in this case. I got some info from this q as well, tho it's not really relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query