# jQuery .ajax() request to PHP proxy not recieving echoed value (FIREFOX ONLY)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox

The following code works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but bonks in Firefox.

First the javascript:

```
$.ajax('/sn.php',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {...stuff},
    complete: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        // do stuff with response...
    }
});
```

and the php relay (on MY server) that uses cURL() to POST or GET from another domain:

```
// setup cURL...
$token = curl_exec($handle);
echo $token;
error_log('token='.$token);
```

$token shows up perfectly in the error_log, and everything works perfect in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox the ajax status is "error" and the responseText is blank. Been banging my head against the wall for a couple days on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox was returning `Status: 0` for the ajax request. Based on a heads up from this [blog post](http://markos.gaivo.net/blog/?p=109) I updated my form to `onSubmit='return false;'`  and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I might be barking up the wrong tree here, but I suspect it's the call to error_log in your php code. If you remove that, does it help?

Also, it might help to set an error handler on your .ajax request too, something like

```
$.ajax('/sn.php',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {...stuff},
    complete: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        // do stuff with response...
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.dir(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

It won't fix the problem, but it'll at least give you some more debug output to look at

*edit* Couple more ideas from [249692](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query/249758). Is your webserver returning the [correct mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query/249758#249758) for the request? Can you try doing a beforeSend and setting [overrideMimeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query/250245#250245)

Comment: Good stuff - didn't even know about console.dir. (1) tried removing error_log, didn't fix it (2) added error status logging, and got: readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, and statusText: "text". nothing too revealing there (3) looking into mime type right now, brb

Comment: Tried setting mime type ('application/json') with beforeSend, didn't work. Also tried setting the mime type in PHP with header('Content-Type: application/json'), to no avail. Good ideas though. Looks like Firefox is more sensitive to mime type errors than the webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't have a native `console.log` like Webkit browsers do. Comment that out or replace it with `alert()` and I bet it works.

Comment: Tried it - no dice. Messages sent to console.log() DO work (I have firebug installed), but good thinking. Any differences between Chrome and Firefox are going to be where the trouble is.