# $.getJSON - ajax is sent but callback function is ignored - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

So here is my function

```
function ajax(addr,loading, loadTo, json){
        addr = addr.replace(' ', '');
        if (loading){
                $("#"+loading).fadeIn();
        }

        if (json){
                $.getJSON(addr, function(data){
                        alert('whoooo working'); // <--- it never goes here
                        if (loading){
                                $("#"+loading).fadeOut();
                        }
                        procJSON(data);
                });
                return true;
        }
}
```

and I'm calling it with

```
var postid = $(this).attr('data-postid');
ajax(url+'tools/delete/'+postid, 'loading'+postid, false, true);
```

ajax is sent, image (loading image) is showed, but callback function is never called.

Isn't that just new reserved value from that IE's big list? Yes I know, IE is not a valid browser, but I can't blame my customers

Comment: What Content-Type does the response have? Should be `application/json`, FWIW. *(Also, this is easy to step through with the built-in debugger - does that give any clues?)*

Comment: I've got no idea, but it is good idea to hardcore it

Comment: @Tomalak: Please answer my question. You're 100% right. Damn, I didn't know IE is so exceptionally

Comment: @Tomalak: As to your question why didn't I use debugger: I never used IE so I hadn't idea IE has tool for developers

Comment: IE 8 onwards has debugging tools at F12. Not as sophisticated as Firebug or Chrome, but they do the job. You can make it emulate the behavior (both JS and rendering engine) of older versions of IE there, too. Go ahead and accept @Guffa's answer. If you want to you can give me an up-vote [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it fails in specific browsers, it's likely that it is a combination of unexpected headers in the response, and how the browser handles the data based on that.

If for example the response has the content type `text/html` instead of `application/json`, the browser might try to turn the response content into a HTML document (by adding `pre` tags around it), which would then cause the JSON parsing to fail.

If you use the `$.ajax` method, you can also catch any error message, which would give you a clue to what's going on:

```
$.ajax({
  url: addr,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    alert('whoooo working'); // <--- it never goes here
    if (loading){
      $("#"+loading).fadeOut();
    }
    procJSON(data);
  },
  error: function(o,c,m) { alert(m); }
});
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively you could watch the network activity in the debugging tools.