# JSON encode adds linefeed as first character

Tags: php, jquery, json

this php:

```
$token = NoCSRF::generate( 'csrf_token' );
$status = "succeed";
$message = "Update done!";
$return = array($status,$message,$token);
//header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

returns

```
"↵["succeed","Update done!","MTQ0NDcxNzM3Nm9nUTRCVzRKOXc5RXFocUZodXh5eXo4Tm5waTlzZ05a"]"
```

to the browser which js can't handle.

If I uncomment the header line in the php it returns

```
["succeed", "Update done!", "MTQ0NDcxNzIyNnAwY01LMVZHdXV6TE1ZT3FZZHhpd2JZcnM0RTl0Rm81"]
```

and works OK

Any idea what's going on here?  I can't just leave the header line uncommented because this solution doesn't work on the live hosted site although it does my dev site as above...

Comment: I would look at the web server software itself as well as any appliances installed in front of the web server.

Comment: you could try `trim` before you echo the content. `echo trim(json_encode($return));`

Comment: @RamRaider tried ltrim; if I check the value of `json_encode($return)` in php it looks fine and ltrim makes no apparent difference to it, yet when I view the variable in js it still has the linefeed character at the start :(

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything (e.g. BOM signature) before opening `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that by default, the json is sent through `text/html`. When using `Content-type: application/json`, the browser is accepting JSON encoded data that can be manipulated in javascript.

More info is available in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).

Comment: @RamRaider I'm only seeing this issue where I'm handling the AJAX send and return using jquery.  So when I'm doing this I get the problem: `$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#find").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(response)
               {` but when I'm doing this it's fine: `XHR.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
            if (XHR.readyState==4 && XHR.status==200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);`

Comment: in my live implementation I have `Content-type: application/json` in place but I still see the problem

Answer (score 0):

@Josh's beforeSend code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query) has sorted this for me:

```
var jsonMimeType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: myURL,
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType(jsonMimeType);
  }
 },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data){
  // do stuff...
 }
});
```