# Google Visualization error; "Not an Array"

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I am trying to use a simple $.ajax GET to retrieve data from an API, and bind it to Google Charts. My API returns this data:

[image]

This is the format that the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable) uses to declare the datatable in-page.  However, when creating the table from downloaded data, the console shows:

> Error: Not an array

Current code is:

```
function LoadJsonData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/Test',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var dt0 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data, false);
            var chart0 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderBody_ctl02'));
            var options0 = { title: 'Some title', width: 400, height: 300 };
            chart0.draw(dt0, options0);
        }
    });
}

google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'table'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(LoadJsonData);
```

Comment: Can you please check the typeof your return data. It may be a string

Comment: What does the raw HTTP look like? are you sure what you've added is what `data` contains? have you added break points into the js?

Comment: `[['Firstname',...etc.` is invalid json, should be `[["FirstName",...`

Comment: in the ajax call above, change -- `dataType: "text"` -- to --> `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @WhiteHat If I do that, the error changes to *First row is not an array*

Comment: _please_ add to `success: function` --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` and share result (with `dataType: "json"`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` accepts an array of **arrays** `[]`:

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable)

> ```
> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>        ['Employee Name', 'Salary'],
>        ['Mike', {v:22500, f:'22,500'}], // Format as "22,500".
>        ['Bob', 35000],
>        ['Alice', 44000],
>        ['Frank', 27000],
>        ['Floyd', 92000],
>        ['Fritz', 18500]
>       ],
>       false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
> ```

Your json/js object is not in the same format as above, it's an array of **objects** `{}`

```
[{},{}...etc.]
```

Reformat your **json** into the correct format. Something along the lines of:

```
[["FirstName", "count"],
["Bob", "60"],
["Wendy", "4"]]
```

Note: the first array (`["FirstName", "count"]`) contains the labels. the following array(s) contain the data. This will be easier to do server side. If you want to do it client side please read [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Its as if the function won't accept the data contents, because they are not declared inside the function call itself.

Comment: It sounds like (It's unclear without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that data isn't an array. Check that data is how you expect it look as above, what you put in your comment should work. PS remember to pass `false` into the call to `arrayToDataTable` if your passing the column headers in the first array @EvilDr

Comment: I think I know what your issue is in json you need to use `"`. So format your **json** `[["FirstName", "count"],["Bob", "60"]..etc]`

Comment: I think you might have it, there.  Is there a way to do this in JQuery/JS, as I don't want to hack the API output logic if it will break stuff elsewhere?

Comment: Updateing the API wouldn't be a hack. It should be returning the data in the above format

Comment: Is `data` an object or a string? `[['firstname',...]` is a valid javascript object but an **invalid json string**

Comment: If data is an object, and it is an array of arrays, everything should now be working then?

Comment: The error is *Error: Not an array*.  I've updated the question to remove all the noise and focus on your advice so far.  Sorry if I've backtracked; my head is spinning

Comment: Are you 100% sure `data` **is an object**? Because your not parsing it, so if your don't specify the right headers it will come out as a string. Your example only shows the HTTP response, what happens if you debug your javascript and add a watch to `data`? This for me, is still suggesting that `data` is not an object but a string.

Comment: Sorry, you are quite correct, it is a string.  God knows how I ended up seeing "object" in the alert earlier.  I've been staring at this far too long.

Comment: I'd imagine your not passing the `application/json` header value with your HTTP request. If you don't tell jQuery "this is json" it won't parse it. The other option is to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: See this question [jQuery won't parse my JSON from AJAX query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query)

Answer (score -2):

Your first row,  `{"FirstName":"Bob", "Count" : 34}` is a JSON object not an array.

Your attempts to JSON.parse the data in your success function will have made an attempt to parse the whole data object.

You you want to parse each item, try the following

```
success: function (data) {
         $.each(data, function(i, value){
              var dt0 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(value));
              var chart0 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolderBody_ctl02'));
             var options0 = { title: 'Some title', width: 400, height: 300 };
             chart0.draw(dt0, options0);
          }
    },
```

Comment: An example would be helpful please, as the JQuery documentation simply shows simple transformations on the array values.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think the map function I suggested before is quite necessary, I noticed you weren't iterating through the items of your request and think this may be why you couldn't just parse each datum!

Comment: There's a bug in your code; it $each should be terminated with `});` not just `}`.  Anyway, it produces the error *JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data*

Comment: `value` would still be in an incorrect format and, yes, this is invalid syntax